# Force quit Terminal.app using Apple Script Editor

Tags: macos, terminal.app, applescript

I'm trying to **force** quit my Terminal.app using Apple Script Editor

```
tell application "Terminal"
    quit
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    key code 53
end tell
```

It does not seem to work. How would one go about and did that ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I found the answer to my owned question

```
tell application "Terminal"
    quit
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending a `quit` command and a `keystroke` doesn't equate to a force-quit.  I assume that the solution you settled upon appeared to work simply because, after being issued a `quit` command, I'm guessing a dialog box popped up asking whether you'd like to force-quit *Terminal*.  Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>—either physically or programmatically—would then select the force-quit option presented to you.

The problem with sending a key press programmatically is that, if the focus unexpectedly changed to another window on your system, that key press would be sent to the wrong window.

One bonafide method of force-quitting an app from AppleScript is to obtain its PID, then issue a `kill` command via a shell script.  It's actually just a single line of code.  Here's what it would look like when used to deal with your situation (formatted over two lines for readability):

```
    tell application "System Events" to ¬
    do shell script "kill -9 " & unix id of process "Terminal"
```

Comment: A simple `do shell script "pkill -9 -x Terminal"` will do the job without then need for **System Events**.

Comment: @user3439894 Ugh, there are a few small but irksome niggles in this answer that I kind of find embarrassing to be reading two years later, wondering why the hell did I used to indent code blocks from line 1. I'm also appalled I headed straight for `SIGKILL`, which is kinda overdoing it and not recommended to be sent by the user. Most force quits are `SIGTERM`. But I must not have known about `pkill` back then, as I never use `kill` now as `pkill` makes it easier, and also has more functionality along with `pgrep`. So, what drew you back here, then? Were you trying to quit Terminal?

Comment: CJK, It got bumped to the top of the cue by [Community](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community), so I took a look at it, that's all. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Ah, ok. Thanks for telling me.  In that case, I shall update the answer as there's enough bad AppleScript and Shell Script examples out there, I should do my best not to add to that if it's possibly getting a wider/renewed exposure.